# Yii: how to allow an action to receive a get parameter of type array?

Tags: php, arrays, http, yii

I need an url like this

```
.../index.php?r=order/send&par[]=a&par[]=b&par[]=c
```

Where the `par` array could be empty.

The goal is to be able to handle `$par` as array

I tried

```
public function actionSend($par = array())
```

But entering the url above, I got an `Invalid request` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pass variable in method eg:

```
public function actionSend(){
   $par = Yii::app()->request->getQuery('par'); 
   // Todo With Par
   print_r($par);
}
```

I've not tested in but it should work.